# working with two ImageView in android

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

This is my `ImageViews`. The *@id/imgUSER* is behind the *@id/imgBG*. But when I click on *imgUSER* it does not respond..  but when I remove the *imgBG* and test it, and click *imgUSER* again then it works. Is there anyway that I can click *imgUSER* if the *imgBG* is visible or present?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgUSER"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="185dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgBG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/products" />
```

Heres my code for listerner

imgUSER.setOnClickListener(listener);

....

public OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.imgUSER :
            imgUSER.setBackgroundResource(R.id.bgProduct_1);

            break;
```

}

Comment: post your code as well.

Comment: `@id/imgUSER is behind the @id/imgBG`, does it have to be that way? If no, you can switch the position of both ImageView. If yes, you can set the OnClickListener to @+id/imgBG instead of @+id/imgUSER.

Comment: @Aprian. yes I have to do it that way for experiment.. =)

Comment: @chinna_82 what code do you want?

Comment: I posted my listener code.. =) for references..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have one Textview above another. Now, only the upper Textview will receive touch event. If you want instead imgUSER to receive it, change onTouchReceiver:

```
imgBG.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     //your code here   
     return false; //this is the key
            }
     });
```

Comment: i've tried it this way public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    
    case R.id.imgUSER:
     imgUSER.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
     Log.i("TEST","TEST");
     break;
    }
    return true

Comment: I think your answer is fine.. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
imgUSER.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {    
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        imgUSER.setBackgroundResource(R.id.bgProduct_1);    
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Use onTouch event. The image change once you touch the image. You can google **"Android onTouch change Image"** to get more sample code.

Comment: Yes.. I get your point.. but what I'm trying to do is change the background of imgUSER if the user clicks on the imgUSER not on the imgBG. =)

Comment: change **`imgBG`** to **`imgUSER`**. Check my answer.

Comment: if user clicks on imgUSER ==> change background of imgUSER and if user clicks on imgBG ==> change background of imgBG.. @chinna_82 The only problem is I can't click on imgUSER cause it is behind imgBG..

Comment: how you want to show the image. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html to understand on layouts.

Comment: lets just say that my imageview are layers.. two layers.. imgBG is the top layer while imgUSER is bottom layer.. imgUSER does not respond onTOuch cause imgBG is on top of it.. so I'm just wondering if ever there is a way to touch imgUSER.. or is it even possible..

Comment: in this case don't use 2 image. You can use linear layout. Set linear layout backgroud as `@drawable/products` and use 1 Imageview for imgUSER. You can do onTouch to change the background

Comment: @chinna_82.. still cant manage it.. cause i need the imgUSER to be behind.. lets just say I have a border that I created for imgUSER and I need that to be on top of my imgUSER..

Comment: hey @chinna_82.. I made a workaround to make it work using OnTouchListener, I give kudos to you =) but I have to accept Roman answer cause he suggested it first.. =) kudos to both of you! =)